# Modules imported in imported modules are not found when using Pytest

Tags: python, python-3.x, pytest

My project structure is as follows:

```
proj/
    src/
        __init__.py
        etc/
            __init__.py
            visitor.py
        obj/
            __init__.py
            node.py
    tests/
        __init__.py
        visitor_tests.py
```

I'm having issues importing `visitor.py` in my `visitor_tests.py` class because there is an import for `node.py` in it which can not be found.

In `visitor_tests.py` i'm importing the visitor itself using:

```
from src.etc.visitor import Visitor
```

But I get the following error:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'obj.node'; 'obj' is not a package.
```

In `visitor.py` I have the following import for node:

```
from obj.node import Node
```

I run the tests using `pytest tests/visitor_tests.py` from the `proj/` root.

Comment: Do you have `__init__.py` files in both the `etc` and `obj` directories?

Comment: Then you may want to consider doing relative imports (I think): in `visitor.py`, write `from ..obj.node import what_i_need_to_import` (and similar in the tests module) See also: https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0328/#rationale-for-absolute-imports

Comment: @darthbith That does work but relative imports seem a bit unnatural to me, in the sense that for larger projects the trailing dots might be pretty cumbersome. Do you know of an alternative solution using absolute imports? Regardless if you post an answer for this I'll accept it.

Comment: Yes, but the point of relative imports is that with absolute imports you don't know where the module may be coming from, and if there is another library that shadows the same name, you don't know which module you're pulling from; hence, with relative imports, you know exactly where the code is coming from (relative to the current code)

Answer (score 0):

instead of using src.etc.visitor,obj.node user sys.path.append in your         visitor_tests.py & visitor.py

```
import sys
sys.path.append("/path/to/obj")
sys.path.append("/path/to/etc")
```